# Issue with pg-config file

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, vercel, pg-config

When I try to deploy my Flask app to Vercel, I'm getting an error.

Error: Command failed: pip3.9 install --disable-pip-version-check --target . --upgrade -r /vercel/path1/requirements.txt
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [21 lines of output]
running egg_info
writing psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt

```
  Error: pg_config executable not found.                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                       
  pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory                                                                                                       
  containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the                                                                                                       
  option:                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                       
      python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                       
  or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                       
  If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI                                                                                                        
  'psycopg2-binary' package instead.                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                       
  For further information ple
```

I installed psycopg2 and psycopg2-binary in env and out of env. I don't know where I must write this **export PATH="D:\Progs\PostgreSQL\bin:$PATH"**. I create .env file but it is not help. I try write path in .json but it is also not help. My pg-config path is D:\Progs\PostgreSQL\bin. My OS is Windows 10

Comment: Did you install the PostgreSQL C headers / build environment?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm only install PostgreSQL v14, i'm using it at first time

Answer (score 0):

All problem was in Pipfile and Pipfile.lock (I use pipenv). I'm not removed psycopg2 from this files, so  remove all files and change my requirements.exe (psycopg2 --> psycopg2-binary) and run this "pipenv update". So all is working. I don't get this error again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).